# "Notice: Array to string conversion" in CakePHP when uploading a file

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.x

I'm having some issues with a form and it's driving me insane.

Whenever I try to upload an image to my database, I get

```
Notice: Array to string conversion [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 1009]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing. Any help is appreciated.

This is my Model

```
        'banner_image' => array(
        'not_required' => array(
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ),
        'is_image' => array(
            'rule' => 'is_image_check',
            'message' => 'We found that the file you uploaded is not an image.',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
),
```

This is my controller

```
/**
 * admin_add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Survey->create();
        if ($this->Survey->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The survey has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The survey could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Survey', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Admin Add Survey'); ?></legend>
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('subtitle');

    if ( empty($this->request->data['Survey']['banner_image']) or isset($this->validationErrors['Survey']['banner_image']) ): 

            echo $this->Form->input('banner_image', array('type'=>'file'));

    else : 

        echo $this->Html->image('/img/surveys/' . $this->request->data['Survey']['banner_image'] ) ;                
        echo $this->Html->link('Remove this image?', '/admin/Surveys/remove_image/' . $this->request->data['Survey']['id'] ) ;
    endif;
    // echo $this->Form->input('listing_image', array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('url_iframe');
    echo $this->Form->input('enable');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Comment: When you post the  form, `banner_image` will not contain the file content. It'll contain `uploaded file information array`. You can read about it here: [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: @user3082321 Thanks for the link. It was a good read.

Comment: @ndm Sorry about that. Next time I'll remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your controller receives for field `banner_image`:

```
$this->request->data['Survey']['banner_image'] = array(
    'name' => 'example_image.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpg',
    'tmp_name' => 'C:/WINDOWS/TEMP/php1EE.tmp', //path will vary on Unix-like OSes
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 41737,
);
```

If you attempt to save this into your table, you will get

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in filename on line X
```

Therefore, you have to do some pre-processing before you can call `save()`.

Your `surveys.banner_image` is probably set to accept a file name.

A typical approach is to implement the `Survey::beforeSave()` callback and add the necessary code to move the uploaded file from its temporary location to the destination folder of your choice.

You then overwrite the `$data['Survey']['banner_image']` array with `$data['Survey']['banner_image']['name']`.

Or, instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use one of the multiple CakePHP plugins which handles uploads, for example [josegonzalez/cakephp-upload](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/tree/2.x).

For further reference, see:

- [`FormHelper::file(string $fieldName, array $options)`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::file)